# HID software device (emulated)

Tags: windows, linux, hid

Do you know any way to make a software (virtual) HID device for Windows and/or Linux?

I want to use some sensors as HID but they don't have any HID so I thought I could have my own HID installed on the PC (the emulated onde) that converts some messages to HID and vice-versa.

Comment: It's certainly possible to write your own device drivers, but very challenging.  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff557573%28v=vs.85%29

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows doesn't have a way; you will have to [simulate mouse and keyboard events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171548.aspx) instead. Linux has [uinput](http://thiemonge.org/getting-started-with-uinput), which will allow you to inject input events directly into the kernel.